# upgrading php 5.1.6 to php 5.2 on plesk 9x?

Tags: php, upgrade, plesk

how can i upgrade from 5.1.6 to 5.2 using plesk, i need this upgrade in order to build my app cheers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this post](http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f15/upgrade-php-parallels-plesk-panel-linux-unix-9412/):

In order to upgrade PHP 5 on a Linux server to the latest version perform the following steps.

Applies to:

- Plesk 8.x for Linux
- Plesk 9.x for Linux

Download the installer script which updates Yum's repositories:

```
[root@server ~]# wget http://78.129.170.254/cpinstall/atomic
--2009-11-12 15:40:22-- http://78.129.170.254/cpinstall/atomic
Connecting to 78.129.170.254:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 8918 (8.7K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `atomic'

100%[=====================================>] 8,918 35.7K/s in 0.2s

2009-11-12 15:40:22 (35.7 KB/s) - `atomic' saved [8918/8918]
```

Execute this downloaded script using the following command:

```
[root@server ~]# sh atomic

Atomic Archive installer, version 1.1
Configuring the [atomic] yum archive for this system

Installing the Atomic GPG key: OK
Downloading atomic-release-1.0-10.el5.art.noarch.rpm: OK

Would you like to add the Plesk yum repository to the system?

Enable Plesk repository? (y/n) [Default: n]: y

Plesk 8.6 and 9.2 repositories are available:
NOTE: Plesk 9 repos are only available for rhel/centos 4 and 5

Enable Plesk 8.6 or 9.2? (8/9) [Default: 8]: 9

The Atomic Rocket Turtle archive has now been installed and configured for your system.

The following channels are available:
atomic - [ACTIVATED] - contains the stable tree of ART packages.
atomic-testing - [DISABLED] - contains the testing tree of ART packages.
atomic-bleeding - [DISABLED] - contains the development tree of ART packages.
```

Now run `yum upgrade php` to upgrade the PHP to the latest version:

```
[root@server ~]# yum upgrade php
```

The PHP upgrade process will commence & will finish within the next 5 minutes.

Finally execute these 3 commands to restart the web services & to accept the new PHP:

```
[root@server ~]# /etc/init.d/psa stopall
[root@server ~]# /etc/init.d/psa startall
[root@server ~]# /etc/init.d/psa restart
```

Now check the newer installed version of PHP using the php -v command.

Comment: @getaway I've never used plesk, just found the above from Googling for you. Perhaps [this](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/923/Using+root+login+with+Plesk) helps you?

Comment: could you access my server for me please, i will give you the details, i will give you 500 points!! im so shit at this